# Installed Galaxy S3 ROM on Galaxy S2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, custom-roms, recovery-mode, unbricking

I installed a ROM meant for **Galaxy S3** on my **Galaxy S2** phone by mistake and now the phone won't boot.

I can get into *Download Mode* fine but I can't get to *Recovery Mode* because the ROM installed a S3 specific recovery as well.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Download Mode and flash Galaxy S2 firmware/recovery using heimdall or Odin (over USB). There's no other way.

Comment: heimdall is IMHO the better way to do this, it's also available for Mac, Win, Linux ([github](https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall/downloads) or original project [site](http://www.glassechidna.com.au/products/heimdall/))